# Why is wrap content in multiple line TextView filling parent?

Tags: android, android-layout, textview

I have a multi line text view set to `android:layout_width="wrap_content"` that, when rendered, takes all available width of the parent. When the text can fit on one line, the `wrap_content` works fine, but at two or more lines, the text view seems to match the parents width, leaving what looks like padding on either side.

Because the text can not fit on one line, is the text view assuming to require all available width? I want the view to be bounded by the smallest possible dimensions.

Any ideas?

For reference, here is layout definition:

```
<TextView
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_centerInParent="true"
    android:singleLine="false"
    android:textSize="24sp"
    android:textStyle="bold"
    android:textColor="@color/white"
    android:gravity="center_horizontal"
/>
```

Comment: The smallest possible width will be most likely almost one word per line... Is it what you are trying to achieve?

Comment: The text parsing and wrapping is fine, but I were to say add a background color, I would see that the width of the view extends to the width of the parent, leaving a padding of sorts on either side of the text. Single line text does not do this but once the text wraps, it seems to assume that it needs all available width. After parsing, it would be nice to somehow have the view relayout and measure to wrap content.

Comment: @Chase : I have the same problem and the answer here did not solve it. Were you able to solve it ? See my question here at: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22970783/correct-textview-padding

Answer (score 57, accepted):

I had the same problem also...
You may use custom TextView with overridden method onMeasure() where you calculate the width:

```
public class WrapWidthTextView extends TextView {

...

@Override
protected void onMeasure(int widthMeasureSpec, int heightMeasureSpec) {
    super.onMeasure(widthMeasureSpec, heightMeasureSpec);

    Layout layout = getLayout();
    if (layout != null) {
        int width = (int) Math.ceil(getMaxLineWidth(layout))
                + getCompoundPaddingLeft() + getCompoundPaddingRight();
        int height = getMeasuredHeight();            
        setMeasuredDimension(width, height);
    }
}

private float getMaxLineWidth(Layout layout) {
    float max_width = 0.0f;
    int lines = layout.getLineCount();
    for (int i = 0; i < lines; i++) {
        if (layout.getLineWidth(i) > max_width) {
            max_width = layout.getLineWidth(i);
        }
    }
    return max_width;
}
}
```

Comment: @Vitaliy Polchuk : Can you please look at a similar question here at: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22970783/correct-textview-padding

Comment: This doesn't work in case you want `gravity="center"` (didn't try left-right), for that to work we need another `onMeasure`, so instead of `setMeasureDimension` call: `super.onMeasure(MeasureSpec.makeMeasureSpec(width, MeasureSpec.getMode(widthMeasureSpec)), heightMeasureSpec);` (code condensed for lack of formatting) it may worth wrapping this call in `if (width < getMeasuredWidth())`...

Comment: I have a LinearLayout with 2 columns: a multiline WrapWidthTextView  on the left and a TextView on the right.

Even though the width of the WrapWidthTextView does not take all the available width, the parent (the LinearLayout) is stretched and takes all the width.

@TWiStErRob code did not help.

Comment: @Petrakeas quick check: is the parent `match_parent` or has layout params which would stretch it? I suggest posting a question if you want help with it...

Comment: @TWiStErRob the parent is "wrap_content".

Comment: I just love how StackOverflow suggested me this answer **after** I asked the similar question, found the solution and answered it myself: http://stackoverflow.com/a/32105203/2299005 (my solution is just like this one, although I used `getLineMax()` instead of `getLineWidth()` for better result)

Comment: This is also helpful for its descendant - a Button. In case of `gravity="center"` the solution works right, at least, at my device.

Comment: Rebuild a project when insert this class, otherwise it won't find it in XML.

Comment: It doesn't work with `android:gravity="end"`. The method of @SergeyKrivenkov helps.

Comment: In Kotlin `getMaxLineWidth(layout)` is `return (0..layout.lineCount).maxOf { layout.getLineWidth(it) }`.

Answer (score 13):

I am late to the party but I hope my solution may be quite useful for somebody because it supports any text alignment/gravity and also RTL. In order to support any alignment, I had also to override onDraw method.

I have written an [article on medium](https://medium.com/@mxdiland/android-textview-multiline-problem-61f8c3499bbb) with an explanation of the implementation.

```
import android.graphics.Canvas
import android.text.Layout
import android.text.Layout.Alignment.ALIGN_CENTER
import android.text.Layout.Alignment.ALIGN_NORMAL
import android.text.Layout.Alignment.ALIGN_OPPOSITE
import android.util.AttributeSet
import androidx.appcompat.widget.AppCompatTextView
import kotlin.math.ceil

/**
 * Created by Max Diland
 */

/**
 * Improved solution
 * https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7439748/why-is-wrap-content-in-multiple-line-textview-filling-parent
 * It is a hacky implementation and because of the hack please use it to display texts only!
 * Now it supports any textAlignment, RTL.
 * What is not supported (supported but unusable):
 * - compound drawables,
 * - background drawables
 */
class AccurateWidthTextView @JvmOverloads constructor(
    context: android.content.Context,
    attrs: AttributeSet? = null,
    defStyleAttr: Int = 0
) : AppCompatTextView(context, attrs, defStyleAttr) {

    private var extraPaddingRight: Int? = null

    override fun onMeasure(widthMeasureSpec: Int, heightMeasureSpec: Int) {
        super.onMeasure(widthMeasureSpec, heightMeasureSpec)
        if (layout == null || layout.lineCount < 2) return

        val maxLineWidth = ceil(getMaxLineWidth(layout)).toInt()
        val uselessPaddingWidth = layout.width - maxLineWidth

        val width = measuredWidth - uselessPaddingWidth
        val height = measuredHeight
        setMeasuredDimension(width, height)
    }

    private fun getMaxLineWidth(layout: Layout): Float {
        return (0 until layout.lineCount)
            .map { layout.getLineWidth(it) }
            .max()
            ?: 0.0f
    }

    override fun onDraw(canvas: Canvas) {
        if (layout == null || layout.lineCount < 2) return super.onDraw(canvas)

        val explicitLayoutAlignment = layout.getExplicitAlignment()
        if (explicitLayoutAlignment == ExplicitLayoutAlignment.MIXED) return super.onDraw(canvas)

        val layoutWidth = layout.width
        val maxLineWidth = ceil(getMaxLineWidth(layout)).toInt()

        if (layoutWidth == maxLineWidth) return super.onDraw(canvas)

        when (explicitLayoutAlignment) {
            ExplicitLayoutAlignment.RIGHT -> {
                drawTranslatedHorizontally(
                    canvas,
                    -1 * (layoutWidth - maxLineWidth)
                ) { super.onDraw(it) }
                return
            }

            ExplicitLayoutAlignment.CENTER -> {
                drawTranslatedHorizontally(
                    canvas,
                    -1 * (layoutWidth - maxLineWidth) / 2
                ) { super.onDraw(it) }
                return
            }

            else -> return super.onDraw(canvas)
        }
    }

    private fun drawTranslatedHorizontally(
        canvas: Canvas,
        xTranslation: Int,
        drawingAction: (Canvas) -> Unit
    ) {
        extraPaddingRight = xTranslation
        canvas.save()
        canvas.translate(xTranslation.toFloat(), 0f)
        drawingAction.invoke(canvas)
        extraPaddingRight = null
        canvas.restore()
    }

    /*
    This textView does not support compound drawables correctly so the function is used not on purpose.
    It affects clipRect's width which gets formed inside the onDraw() method.
    Negative - increases.
    Positive - shrinks
    So before onDraw you should set some value to the field extraPaddingRight
    to change clip rect bounds and set null right after onDraw
     */
    override fun getCompoundPaddingRight(): Int {
        return extraPaddingRight ?: super.getCompoundPaddingRight()
    }
}

/*
It does not matter whether the text is LTR or RLT at the end of the day it is either aligned left
or right or centered. Mixed means the layout has more than 1 paragraph and the paragraphs have
different alignments
 */
private enum class ExplicitLayoutAlignment {
    LEFT, CENTER, RIGHT, MIXED
}

private fun Layout.getExplicitAlignment(): ExplicitLayoutAlignment {
    if (lineCount == 0) return ExplicitLayoutAlignment.LEFT

    val explicitAlignments = (0 until this.lineCount)
        .mapNotNull { this.getLineExplicitAlignment(it) }
        .distinct()

    return if (explicitAlignments.size > 1) {
        ExplicitLayoutAlignment.MIXED
    } else {
        explicitAlignments.firstOrNull() ?: ExplicitLayoutAlignment.LEFT
    }
}

private fun Layout.getLineExplicitAlignment(line: Int): ExplicitLayoutAlignment? {
    if (line !in 0 until this.lineCount) return null

    val isDirectionLtr = getParagraphDirection(line) == Layout.DIR_LEFT_TO_RIGHT
    val alignment = getParagraphAlignment(line)

    return when {
        alignment.name == "ALIGN_RIGHT" -> ExplicitLayoutAlignment.RIGHT
        alignment.name == "ALIGN_LEFT" -> ExplicitLayoutAlignment.LEFT
        // LTR and RTL
        alignment == ALIGN_CENTER -> ExplicitLayoutAlignment.CENTER
        // LTR
        isDirectionLtr && alignment == ALIGN_NORMAL -> ExplicitLayoutAlignment.LEFT
        isDirectionLtr && alignment == ALIGN_OPPOSITE -> ExplicitLayoutAlignment.RIGHT
        // RTL
        alignment == ALIGN_NORMAL -> ExplicitLayoutAlignment.RIGHT
        else -> ExplicitLayoutAlignment.LEFT
    }
}
```

Comment: That should be the accepted answer! Thanks, Max. You saved my time

Comment: This was super helpful. `max()` needs to be updated to `maxOrNull()` for newer versions of Kotlin but otherwise did the job perfectly.

Comment: Problem, ```binding.featureTitle.text``` Unresolved reference: text

Comment: (binding.featureTitle as TextView).text solved the problem

Answer (score 8):

A little bit optimized solution for the accepted answer above:

```
@Override
protected void onMeasure(int widthSpec, int heightSpec) {
    int widthMode = MeasureSpec.getMode(widthSpec);

    // if wrap_content 
    if (widthMode == MeasureSpec.AT_MOST) {
        Layout layout = getLayout();
        if (layout != null) {
            int maxWidth = (int) Math.ceil(getMaxLineWidth(layout)) + 
                           getCompoundPaddingLeft() + getCompoundPaddingRight();
            widthSpec = MeasureSpec.makeMeasureSpec(maxWidth, MeasureSpec.AT_MOST);
        }
    }
    super.onMeasure(widthSpec, heightSpec);
}
```

Comment: Such implementation supports gravity="center_horizontal" case, upvoting.

Comment: It doesn't work because `getLayout()` returns null until `super.onMeasure(widthSpec, heightSpec)` is called. So you need to call `super.onMeasure(widthSpec, heightSpec);` twice: first time at the very beginning of the overriden method and the second time – at the end.

Answer (score 1):

Based on @Vitaliy answer, converted to Kotlin in case anyone prefers that:

```
class WrapWidthTextView @JvmOverloads constructor(
        context: android.content.Context,
        attrs: AttributeSet? = null,
        defStyleAttr: Int = 0
) : TextView(context, attrs, defStyleAttr) {

    override fun onMeasure(widthMeasureSpec: Int, heightMeasureSpec: Int) {
        super.onMeasure(widthMeasureSpec, heightMeasureSpec)
        val layout = this.layout ?: return
        val width = ceil(getMaxLineWidth(layout)).toInt() + compoundPaddingLeft + compoundPaddingRight
        val height = measuredHeight
        setMeasuredDimension(width, height)
    }

    private fun getMaxLineWidth(layout: Layout): Float {
        var maxWidth = 0.0f
        val lines = layout.lineCount
        for (i in 0 until lines) {
            if (layout.getLineWidth(i) > maxWidth) {
                maxWidth = layout.getLineWidth(i)
            }
        }
        return maxWidth
    }
}
```

And used in XML normally like any other `TextView`:

```
<com.yourpackage.WrapWidthTextView
                            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                            ...
                            />
```

Answer (score 0):

In case someone has the same problem for Material Buttons, here is the class I am using to avoid the button to fill the parent. It still works when an icon is set. The max line width calculation is based on the other answers in this post.

```kotlin
import android.content.Context
import android.graphics.Canvas
import android.text.Layout
import android.util.AttributeSet
import com.google.android.material.button.MaterialButton
import kotlin.math.ceil

/**
 * A material button that does not automatically fill the parent when it is multiline
 * but orientates on the widest line while still being compatible with icons
 */
class WrapWidthMaterialButton : MaterialButton {

    constructor(context: Context) : super(context)

    constructor(context: Context, attrs: AttributeSet) : super(context, attrs)

    constructor(context: Context, attrs: AttributeSet, defStyleAttr: Int)
            : super(context, attrs, defStyleAttr)

    private var actualWidthToParentWidthDifference = 0
    private var isDrawing = false

    override fun onMeasure(widthMeasureSpec: Int, heightMeasureSpec: Int) {
        super.onMeasure(widthMeasureSpec, heightMeasureSpec)
        if (layout == null || layout.lineCount < 2) return

        val actualWidth = getActualWidth(layout)
        if (actualWidth < measuredWidth) {
            actualWidthToParentWidthDifference = measuredWidth - actualWidth
            setMeasuredDimension(actualWidth, measuredHeight)
        }

    }

    /**
     * computes the actual width the view should be measured to by using the width
     * of the widest line plus the paddings for the compound drawables
     */
    private fun getActualWidth(layout: Layout): Int {
        val maxLineWidth = (0 until layout.lineCount)
            .map { layout.getLineWidth(it) }
            .maxOrNull() ?: 0.0f
        return ceil(maxLineWidth).toInt() + compoundPaddingLeft + compoundPaddingRight
    }

    override fun onDraw(canvas: Canvas) {
        isDrawing = true
        super.onDraw(canvas)
        isDrawing = false
    }

    /**
     * a workaround to make the TextView.onDraw method draw the text in the new centre of the view
     * by substracting half of the actual width difference from the returned value
     * This should only be done during drawing however, since otherwise the initial width calculation will fail
     */
    override fun getCompoundPaddingLeft(): Int {
        return super.getCompoundPaddingLeft().let { value ->
            if (isDrawing) value - actualWidthToParentWidthDifference / 2 else value
        }
    }


}
```