# Resize multi-line textview to correct size

Tags: java, android, android-layout

I have a TextView whose text is too big to fit on one line, so it displays my full text on separate lines. However, the width of the TextView now takes up the full screen, even though the text itself does not.

For example, say my text is "Some long text".
Get's displayed like this:

Some long
text

I've defined the TextView using wrap_content.

```
<TextView 
    android:id="@+id/txtMainText" 
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="Some long text"
    android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge"
    android:textColor="#000000" />
```

I want the TextView's width to be the width of "Some long", not wider. How do I do it?

Thanks

Comment: possible duplicate of [Why is wrap content in multiple line TextView filling parent?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7439748/why-is-wrap-content-in-multiple-line-textview-filling-parent)

Answer (score 0):

two method to  solve :

one is:

set parent layout's layout_width = wrap_content

ther other is :

in your code measure the textview's width,and set width

Comment: As I had the same problem, I wanted to try your solution, but I'm already using your first method. Sadly, it doesn't work.

Answer (score 0):

As @EarlGrey said, see [Why is wrap content in multiple line TextView filling parent?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7439748/why-is-wrap-content-in-multiple-line-textview-filling-parent).

```
public class WrapWidthTextView extends AppCompatTextView {

    public WrapWidthTextView(Context context) {
        super(context);
    }

    public WrapWidthTextView(Context context, @Nullable AttributeSet attrs) {
        super(context, attrs);
    }

    public WrapWidthTextView(Context context, @Nullable AttributeSet attrs, int defStyleAttr) {
        super(context, attrs, defStyleAttr);
    }

    @Override
    protected void onMeasure(int widthSpec, int heightSpec) {
        int widthMode = MeasureSpec.getMode(widthSpec);

        // If wrap_content.
        if (widthMode == MeasureSpec.AT_MOST) {
            Layout layout = getLayout();
            if (layout != null) {
                int maxWidth = (int) Math.ceil(getMaxLineWidth(layout)) +
                        getCompoundPaddingLeft() + getCompoundPaddingRight();
                widthSpec = MeasureSpec.makeMeasureSpec(maxWidth, MeasureSpec.AT_MOST);
            }
        }
        super.onMeasure(widthSpec, heightSpec);
    }

    private float getMaxLineWidth(Layout layout) {
        float max_width = 0f;
        int lines = layout.getLineCount();
        for (int i = 0; i < lines; i++) {
            if (layout.getLineWidth(i) > max_width) {
                max_width = layout.getLineWidth(i);
            }
        }
        return max_width;
    }
}
```

In XML:

```
<com.your_package.WrapWidthTextView
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    ... 
/>
```

Don't forget to rebuild a project to see changes in XML.