# Correct TextView Padding

Tags: android, android-layout, textview

I am populating a `TextView` programmatically. The `layout_width` of `TextView` is set to `wrap_content`.

`wrap_content` works fine when the text fits into one line, but for two or more lines, the text view width seems to match the parents width, so that padding is not respected in the second line.

For example, this is how it displays some sample text.

[image]

Notice how the word 'responding'  in the third line does not respect padding and instead matches the parent's width.

How to correct this ?

Comment: I'm not sure about this, but you could try setting the padding on the layout itself rather than the element.  Either that, or try Margin.

Comment: nope that didn't work :(.. thnks anyways for answering :)

Comment: I would try using weights here; for instance have two empty textviews or just views both on the left and right and set their weights to 1 and then for the real content. set the weight to 3 and padding for your main textview;

Comment: Hmm...  I tried.  I find that margins and padding on the Android are just as frustrating as CSS.  You have to just keep trying things until you get desired results.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7439748/why-is-wrap-content-in-multiple-line-textview-filling-parent

Comment: @ridoy : the solution there did not solve the issue.

Answer (score 0):

Try to set padding to its parent layout. That will be work, if I understand correctly.