# Cannot wrap blockquote-like TextView of arbitrary line count by width

Tags: android, android-layout, textview

I need to render a quote block of arbitrary length. The text must be aligned to the left, while the block itself aligned to the right, similar to this one:
[image: example]

For that I'm trying a `TextView` with `android:width="wrap_content"`, `android:gravity="start"`, and `android:layout_gravity="end"`. However, this works as expected only when the text fits into single line — if text is longer than that, the `TextView` behaves like this:

- 1st quote block is simply a sentence with spaces — devours all parent's width;
- 2nd block — some spaces are non-breaking: `Raw&#160;persistence may&#160;be the only&#160;option other&#160;than giving&#160;up&#160;entirely.` — still the block behaves like `match_parent`.
- 3rd block uses explicit line break — looks the closest to what's required, however that's the least flexible option, and there's still some extra padding on the right.

[image: screenshot]

Here's the layout (`paddingRight` was replaced with `layout_marginRight` for highlight purpose — the behavior is the same either way):

```
<LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="vertical">

    <TextView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_gravity="end"
            android:textAppearance="@style/TextAppearance.AppCompat.Body1"
            android:lineSpacingExtra="3.5dp"
            android:paddingLeft="24dp"
            android:layout_marginRight="24dp"
            android:text="Raw persistence may be the only option other than giving up entirely."
            />

    <TextView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_gravity="end"
            android:textAppearance="@style/TextAppearance.AppCompat.Body1"
            android:lineSpacingExtra="3.5dp"
            android:paddingLeft="24dp"
            android:layout_marginRight="24dp"
            android:text="Raw&#160;persistence may&#160;be the only&#160;option other&#160;than giving&#160;up&#160;entirely."
            />

    <TextView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_gravity="end"
            android:textAppearance="@style/TextAppearance.AppCompat.Body1"
            android:lineSpacingExtra="3.5dp"
            android:paddingLeft="24dp"
            android:layout_marginRight="24dp"
            android:text="@string/Raw persistence may be the only option\nother than giving up entirely."
            />

</LinearLayout>
```

Is there a way to lay this out adequately, without having to resort to multiple strings for different device width etc? =\

Comment: if you want a specific width, give it a specific width. by using `wrap_content` you tell it to expand as much as required.

Comment: I don't need specific width — I need to have this block float to the right regardless of how many lines it takes. I cannot fix the width because different devices may have different fonts etc.

Comment: How do you expect the textview to figure out the width it needs, if you don't tell it?

Comment: Uhm, every view measures itself, in onMeasure method? I'd expect it to measure itself after it has distributed the text in lines

Comment: And how exactly is the `TextView` supposed to know how to "distribute the text in lines"? In this case you tell it that it could go on one line until it is the same size as the parent (which is full screen width). If you want the text wrapped it is one of the following: a) you break it yourself (the way you did it with the line breaks); or b) you impose some width limits, which will the `TextView` to wrap (this can be done by: `layout_width`, `maxWidth` or placing it into a container whose width is based on weight (percentage of the parent width))

Comment: @N.T. See my answer. After the words are wrapped based on maximum available width, there might be space left in the ends of the lines especially when the words are long. Anyway, I found the solution.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

OK, after some examination of `TextView`'s code I put together the solution that does what I need:

```
package com.actinarium.persistence.common;

import android.annotation.TargetApi;
import android.content.Context;
import android.os.Build;
import android.text.Layout;
import android.util.AttributeSet;
import android.widget.TextView;

public class BlockquoteTextView extends TextView {
    public BlockquoteTextView(Context context) {
        super(context);
    }

    public BlockquoteTextView(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
        super(context, attrs);
    }

    public BlockquoteTextView(Context context, AttributeSet attrs, int defStyleAttr) {
        super(context, attrs, defStyleAttr);
    }

    @TargetApi(Build.VERSION_CODES.LOLLIPOP)
    public BlockquoteTextView(Context context, AttributeSet attrs, int defStyleAttr, int defStyleRes) {
        super(context, attrs, defStyleAttr, defStyleRes);
    }

    @Override
    protected void onMeasure(int widthMeasureSpec, int heightMeasureSpec) {
        super.onMeasure(widthMeasureSpec, heightMeasureSpec);

        // Now fix width
        float max = 0;
        Layout layout = getLayout();
        for (int i = 0, size = layout.getLineCount(); i < size; i++) {
            final float lineWidth = layout.getLineMax(i);
            if (lineWidth > max) {
                max = lineWidth;
            }
        }

        final int height = getMeasuredHeight();
        final int width = (int) Math.ceil(max) + getCompoundPaddingLeft() + getCompoundPaddingRight();

        setMeasuredDimension(width, height);
    }
}
```

The default implementation of `onMeasure` does not take line widths into account unless they are broken down by `\n`'s ([code](http://grepcode.com/file/repository.grepcode.com/java/ext/com.google.android/android/5.1.1_r1/android/widget/TextView.java#TextView.desired%28android.text.Layout%29)). I used `getLineMax` instead of `getLineWidth` because the latter measured trailing whitespace — the culprit of misalignment in block #3 in the original post.

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure of this but may work try adding dummy views with weight like this

```
<LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:weightSum="100"
        android:orientation="horizontal">
    <View
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"       
    android:layout_weight="50"
    android:layout_width="0dp"/>
    <TextView
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_weight="50"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_gravity="end"
            android:textAppearance="@style/TextAppearance.AppCompat.Body1"
            android:lineSpacingExtra="3.5dp"
            android:paddingLeft="24dp"
            android:layout_marginRight="24dp"
            android:text="Raw persistence may be the only option other than giving up entirely."
            />
</LinearLayout>
```

I have never tested this so give it a try...