# TextView works wrong with breakStrategy="balanced" and layout_width="wrap_content"

Tags: android, textview

I have such layout (I've removed some attributes, cause they really doesn't matter, full demo project is [here](https://github.com/shomeser/TextView-BreakStrategy)):

```
<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical">

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"      (* this is important)
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:breakStrategy="balanced"         (* this is important)
        android:text="@string/long_text" />
</LinearLayout>
```

The text `long_text` is quite long, so it would be separated for a few lines.

Two important lines are `android:layout_width="wrap_content"` and `android:breakStrategy="balanced"`.

I expect that `TextView` will calculate width according to the actual **text** width, but it doesn't.

[image: screenshot]

Does anybody know how to fix this?

**UPDATE**

Attribute `android:breakStrategy="balanced"` works only for `API 23` and higher. In my example text takes 3 lines, and `balanced` strategy makes each line approximately same width.

I expect that in this case width of view itself will be the same as the longest line.

I'm looking for any workaround. I need solution like in Hangouts chat. I can't figure out how it works.

**UPDATE 2**

Unfortunately, accepted answer doesn't work with RTL text.

Comment: What do you meant by 'I expect that TextView will calculate width according to the actual text width, but it doesn't'
Also your actual seems different than what should have been [like this](https://imagebin.ca/v/38OTigaIafpF)

Comment: I've updated question.

Comment: @Oleksii Kropachov How you expect to break lines , lets say its more lengthy than 1.5 lines .. so whats your expected output ?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

This happens because when TextView calculates its width it measure all text as 1 line (in your case) and on this step it knows nothing about android:breakStrategy. So it is trying to utilize all available space to render as much text on first line as it can.

To get more details, please check method `int desired(Layout layout)` [here](https://github.com/android/platform_frameworks_base/blob/master/core/java/android/widget/TextView.java)

To fix it you can use this class:

```
public class MyTextView extends TextView {
public MyTextView(Context context) {
    super(context);
}

public MyTextView(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
    super(context, attrs);
}

@Override
protected void onMeasure(int widthMeasureSpec, int heightMeasureSpec) {
    super.onMeasure(widthMeasureSpec, heightMeasureSpec);

    Layout layout = getLayout();
    if (layout != null) {
        int width = (int) Math.ceil(getMaxLineWidth(layout))
                + getCompoundPaddingLeft() + getCompoundPaddingRight();
        int height = getMeasuredHeight();
        setMeasuredDimension(width, height);
    }
}

private float getMaxLineWidth(Layout layout) {
    float max_width = 0.0f;
    int lines = layout.getLineCount();
    for (int i = 0; i < lines; i++) {
        if (layout.getLineWidth(i) > max_width) {
            max_width = layout.getLineWidth(i);
        }
    }
    return max_width;
}
```

}

which I took here - [Why is wrap content in multiple line TextView filling parent?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7439748/why-is-wrap-content-in-multiple-line-textview-filling-parent)

Comment: Today I've realized that it doesn't work with RTL text.

Answer (score 1):

You'll need to measure the width of the text in `TextView` programatically, like so:

```
Rect bounds = new Rect();
textView.getPaint().getTextBounds(textView.getText().toString(), 0, textView.getText().length(), bounds);
```

Now, you can place a colored rectangle behind the `TextView`, and set its width programatically after measuring the text (I'm using `FrameLayout` to put the Views one on top of the other, but you can use `RelativeLayout` as well):

XML:

```
<FrameLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <View
        android:id="+@id/background"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:background="@color/green" />

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:breakStrategy="balanced"
        android:text="@string/long_text" />
</FrameLayout>
```

Code:

```
Rect bounds = new Rect();
textView.getPaint().getTextBounds(textView.getText().toString(), 0, textView.getText().length(), bounds);
View bg = findViewById(R.id.background);
gb.getLayoutParams().width = bounds.width();
```

Code is untested, but I'm sure you get the point.

**UPDATE**

It may be possible to do this without using a second background `view`, by setting the `TextView` width to match `bounds.width()`, but this trigger a change in how the text breaks, so need to be careful not to cause an infinite loop.

Comment: I tried this earlier, but `textView.getPaint().getTextBounds()` doesn't work as expected.