# TextView dinamically split text into 2 equal lines

Tags: android, textview

I need to have a TextView that will divide its text into 2 equally long lines, then shrink its width to the size of the resulting lines of text.

android:breakStrategy="balanced" seems to do the text splitting part.

android:layout_width="wrap_content" does not narrow the textView to the width of the text.

Comment: How is showing your textView with the android:layout_width="wrap_content" property?

Comment: As wide as the screen.

Answer (score 0):

With a little research I found your exact problem in another thread.
Thats the solution to your problem:

https://stackoverflow.com/a/41573619/14327871